# How to apply class to the active tab page from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a [chrome extension](https://github.com/xkeshav/givememask) in which one can select a color scheme from list given in popup and apply it to the open (highlighted) tab. From one of code snippet I comes to know that using  `code : "document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"` in [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) change the background color. but there is only one line in `code`.

What my steps are

- select the color scheme from popup
- get the class name of the selected `li`
- apply that class to the DOM document

Please see the code below

#### popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener('click', click);
  }
});

function click(e) {
  // console.log(e.target.className); // gives correct value
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {       
     code : "var scriptOptions = { param1: e.target.className} ;"}, function(e){
      console.log('clicked class');
      console.info(param1);  // gives nothing
      document.body.setAttribute('class', e.target.className);
    });
   window.close();
}
```

- How to get `e.target.className` inside function(e) ?

again If I use jquery. it changed the that popup background color only, see the code

```
    $(function(){
      console.log('jQuery added');
      $(document).on ('click', 'li', function(){
       var cl = this.className;
       $('body').removeClass().addClass(cl);
     });
 });
```

Please tell me

- What is the proper way to accomplish this in both javascript and jQuery

Comment: There are just too many issues with your code / your understanding to make a coherent answer.

Comment: Please tell me the issues.I have added only the relevant code. it's working till now.

Comment: Then please try to structure your question better, it's unclear what exactly you're asking. Maybe break this question up into multiple questions.

Comment: @Xan : Please see the updated question. Is something there still unclear then let me know.

Comment: It is a better question now, yes.

Comment: I'm answering, but not removing the downvote; your question is too specific to be useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - *How to get e.target.className inside function(e) ?*

Let's look at the following sample code:

```js
var a = 1;

function f(a) {
  alert(a);
}

f(2);
```

This is a simplified version of your problem. There is a variable `a` in the global scope, but by naming your function parameter `a` you're essentially making a local variable of the same name.

In your code:

```
function click(e) {
  // e is now from click(e)
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {       
    code : "var scriptOptions = { param1: e.target.className} ;"}, function(e){
      // e is now from function(e)
  });
}
```

The solution is simple: you're not using the parameter of the callback of `executeScript`, so just use `function() { /* ... */ }` as a callback.

---

> *If I use jQuery, it changes the popup background color only*

Your code operates in the context of your popup; `$('body')` refers to popup's body. Same with `document.body` - the callback of `executeScript` executes in the popup.

To change the active tab, this needs to be done from the content script in that tab.

---

> What is the proper way to accomplish this

While you could just inject code, it's better to make a content script that waits for a command.

```
// content.js
if(!injected) { // Make sure it's only executed once
  injected = true;
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(message.action == "bodyClass") {
      document.body.setAttribute('class', message.class);
    }
  });
}
```

Then from the popup, you inject this script then message it:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
  // requires only activeTab permission
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content.js"}, function() {
    // This code executes in the popup after the content script code executes
    //   so it is ready for the message
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "bodyClass", class: "example"});
  });
});
```

If you need jQuery, you need to inject it first:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "jquery.js"}, function() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content.js"}, function() {
    /* content script ready */
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can define the script in the manifest and not inject it every time, but this potentially drains memory as it is injected in tabs where it is not needed.

Comment: can we set `content.js` in manifest.js **content_script** section and remove that line `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

Comment: The code in the property `code` is NOT executed in the context of the popup. It is sent to another page to be executed there. Therefore, you get undefined values (as expected). And yes, you can remove `executeScript` if you set it in the manifest - it's just less efficient that way.

Comment: where do we got that value then, in current code scope.

Comment: It's `e.target.className`. That `code` won't work by the way, since `e.target.className` will not be substituted with its value and it's undefined on the receiving side.

Comment: Is there any other approach except adding in `script.js`? and please suggest me the flaws in my current code.

Comment: sometimes I am getting error `Attempting to use a disconnected port object`

Comment: Do you understand all those problems are NOT connected to your question? You're being a [help vampire](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm) here. It's getting off-topic, we can discuss some more at [the chat I just created](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64399/chrome-extensions-apps).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64455/discussion-between-diecho-and-xan).

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in chromium and in chrome I need to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)`(`**e.target.className**`)` the  before sending via `code`

```
 code : "var scriptOptions = { selectedClass: "  +  JSON.stringify(cl) + " }"
```

from [chorme.sendMessage documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

> Sending a request from the extension to a content script looks very
>   similar, except that **you need to specify which tab to send it to**.

```
function click(e) {
   var cl = e.target.className; // both gives the same result that is OK.
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, highlighted: true, currentWindow: true }, function(htab) {
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(htab, ['active', 'id', 'index', 'windowId', 'title', 'url'], 4));
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(htab[0].id, {
      code : "var scriptOptions = { selectedClass:" + JSON.stringify(cl) + " }" }, function() {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(htab[0].id, { file: "js/script.js" }, function(){
            console.log('Inside script file');
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(htab[0].id, { action: "bodyColor" }, function(resp) {
              console.log('response aaya');
            });
          });
    });
  });
}
```