# How to get and set value on active tab using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developing easy extension, but I have a problem with that :(

I would like to get the value of the existing field by getElementByID 
and also type predefined value for the field.

So i created manfiest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name": "browser_action",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "author": "author",
    "browser_action":
    {

    "default_title": "Use this",
    "default_popup":"popup/popup.html"

    },
    "permissions": [
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"   ],

    "background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent":false
    }}
```

Then popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script language='javascript' src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='testForm'>
        <input type='button' id='alertButton' value='click me'>
    </form>

     <input type='button' id='setButton' value='Set data'>


</body></html>
```

I have background.js which is empty file.
And popup.js which looks like:

```
    function myAlert(){
    alert('hello world');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('alertButton').addEventListener('click', myAlert);
});


function setData(){
    document.getElementById("id1").value='New value';


}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('setButton').addEventListener('click', setData);
});
```

When I click first button, I can see alert, when I trying to set the value to the field on active tab, nothing happens. But If I add element to the popup.htm file with name: id1, so the value is changed.

It looks that it is doing on popup.html file. How to manipulate this on active tab?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

Note: use ["activeTab"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission if DOM modifications are performed only after clicking something in the popup because you don't need the overly aggressive permissions `"http://*/*"` and `"https://*/*"` that show a warning "your extension can modify data on sites that the user visits."

See also:

- [How to apply class to the active tab page from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26776379)
- the official [sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:executescript)